# @Intertceptors does not work for web bean for JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
@Interceptors(MyInterceptor.class)
public class BeanWeb implements Serializable {
    public String methodThrowException throws Exception() {
        throws new Exception();
    }
}

public class MyInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        try {
            return ic.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

For **@Stateless** beans interceptor **works**, but for the **BeanWeb** interceptor **does not work**. And we have never entered into "intercept" method.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How could intercept method calls in BeanWeb?

P.S.: All this spin under Glassfish 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
@Named
@Stateful
@ConversationScoped
@Interceptors(MyInterceptor.class)
public class BeanWeb implements Serializable {
    public String methodThrowException throws Exception() {
        throws new Exception();
    }
}

public class MyInterceptor implements Serializable {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        try {
            return ic.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is correct.